# Hide a div with Jquery not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide a div based off another radio group selection. Only if the value for the first group of radio buttons equals 3 should the bottom set be shown. I just can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong here?

HTML:

```
<label>
  <input name="Weekend" type="radio" id="Weekend_0"  class="Weekend" value="1"  checked="checked" />
  Saturday</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Weekend" value="2" class="Weekend" id="Weekend_1" />
  Sunday</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input name="Weekend" type="radio" id="Weekend_2" class="Weekend" value="3" />
  No</label>

<br />

<div class="wrapper">

  <label>
    <input name="AMPM" type="radio" id="AMPM_0" value="1" checked="checked" />
    AM</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="AMPM" value="2" id="AMPM_1" />
    PM</label>
  <br />

</div>
```

JS:

```
$('input:radio[name="Weekend"]').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.val() == 3 ) {
        $this.nextAll('.wrapper').show();
    } else {
        $this.nextAll('.wrapper').hide();
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/AwYjY/88/)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe the input belongs inside the label

Comment: @andrew it should be fine - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Examples and http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1 and http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simplified JS:** http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/AwYjY/92/

```
$('input:radio[name="Weekend"]').click(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() == "3" ) { //de #1
        $('.wrapper').show();     //de #2
    } else {
        $('.wrapper').hide();     //de #2
    }
});
```

**Notes:**

- For #1: you need to use the text value, not an integer value.
- For #2: you can reference `.wrapper` directly, as your code is.

---

**Expanded JS:** http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/AwYjY/91/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:radio[name="Weekend"]').click(function () {
        toggleAMPM($(this).val())
    });
    $('input:radio[name="Weekend"]').each(function (i, e) {
        if ( $(e).is(':checked') ) toggleAMPM( $(e).val() )
    });
});

function toggleAMPM(field) {
    if (field == "3") {
        $('.wrapper').show();
    } else {
        $('.wrapper').hide();
    }
}
```

---

In my version, the expanded one, you also have the toggle functionality running on pageload, which it does not do in the simplified version! You might want to consider the second option shown.

Comment: Very glad to help. Check out the updated answer for a second option you might want to use... running the functionality on pageload too.

Answer (score 0):

The `.wrapper` isn't a sibling of the radio buttons. Try this:

```
$this.parent().nextAll('.wrapper').show();
```

or

```
$this.parent().siblings('.wrapper').show();
```

And if you want to simplify:

http://jsfiddle.net/ENv2y/

```
$('input:radio[name="Weekend"]').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().siblings('.wrapper').toggle($this.val() == 3);
});
```